# Testing react-native on actual device without a running packaging manager

Tags: react-native

I'm developing a small react-native application for my Android phone. During the development process, I've had the packaging manager running on my computer, and tested the application on my device.

I've also made a release, and copied the apk-file onto my device and installed it there, so that I can test the application without a running packaging server in the background.

The latter is quite cumbersome, so I'd like a way to test the application on my device, and bring the device with me, without going through the hoops of building the application and copying the apk-file onto my device for installation.

How are other's doing this, how do you test your application while away from your computer (and packaging manager)?

Comment: You can do this by using [Expo](https://expo.io/), but it will require making some modifications to your app.  Expo allows you access your package manager over the internet and to publish your package to the cloud.

Comment: BTW, the official React Native site now [recommends creating new apps with Expo](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/getting-started.html).

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Actually, I've bootstrapped my project using https://infinite.red/ignite, and they currently don't support the Create React App (https://github.com/facebookincubator/create-react-app) and thus not Expo. But I guess it would be possible to modify my project to get Expo going, but would Expo allow me to use my app even without internet connectivity? I'm quite new to Expo, so I don't have a thorough understanding of how it works, but I assume you need a package manager running just like I do now.

Comment: Expo allows you to package your code and upload it to the cloud.  Once that is done you will not need to have a package manager running.  However, your mobile device will need to be connected to the internet in order to download the package from Expo's cloud service.  Once the app is compiled for deployment, the package code is included in the compiled app, but any assets (fonts and images) will need to be downloaded from the internet the first time the app is run on a device.  After the first run, the assets can be loaded from cache.

Comment: This seems like a decent setup, assuming I can get it to work on my current project. How would the development cycle typically look like - when I modify the code and want to see the result on my device, I'll have Expo package it and upload it to the cloud, and then view the result on my device?

Comment: The  React Native and Expo documentation can walk you through that.  Basically, you will need to download the Expo app on your mobile device and then access your package via the Expo app.  You can run the package manager on your local machine and when you update the code, Expo will hot load the update.  If you publish to the cloud, you may need to reload the app after an update.  However, you can run the package manager locally and access it from the internet giving you the ability to test your app from anywhere.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I got it working without Expo (due to using the excellent Ignite tool, which doesn't yet support Expo), simply by following these steps:

1. Connect the device to the computer
2. Run "adb reverse tcp:8081 tcp:8081"
3. Run "react-native run-android"
4. Enable Live Reload in the application

This way I can disconnect my device from the computer at any time, and the application will still work properly.

Answer (score 1):

I've found [Fabric + Fastlane + Beta + Crashlytics](https://get.fabric.io/) to be great for that. It may sound pretty complex but [the docs](https://docs.fabric.io/) are great, and there's even [a page that creates the initial config for you](https://fabric.io/features/distribution).

The combination of the above tools let you distribute your app to anyone and gather any errors testers may encounter.

If you're after Android only, you may want to skip Beta and use the [Google Play beta track](https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/3131213?hl=en-GB) directly.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I looks like an interesting project, although maybe somewhat overkill for my needs. Anyway, if I were to implement this setup, I would modify the code, run the setup to deploy to say Google Play, then install/update the app on my device? Then test it, and repeat the process?

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by using [Expo](http://www.expo.io), but it will require making some modifications to your app. Expo allows you access your package manager over the internet and to publish your package to the cloud.

Furthermore, the official React Native site now [recommends creating new apps using Expo](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/getting-started.html).

After you publish your package to Expo's cloud, you will not need to have a package manager running to use your app.  However, your mobile device will need to be connected to the internet in order to download the package from the cloud. When you are ready to deploy to an app store, Expo will let you compile your app with the React Native javascript included.  The compiled app will need an internet connection to download assets (images and fonts) initially.  However, after the first load, assets can be retrieved from cache.

Expo will also let you run a package manager on your local machine and tunnel that connection over the internet.  This allows your mobile device to connect to your local package manager from anywhere online.

Expo is not for everyone, and there are definitely some limitations.  However, it does allow you to test your app from anywhere.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I'll look more into Expo, and see if I get a good workflow going. I remember a few years back, when I developed a simple Android application, I just plugged my Android device into the computer, tested the code, and when I inplugged the device the app were still fully functional. When I was ready for it, I released the app on Google Play. That workflow worked great for my usecase, and I'm hoping I'll get a similar going with this new setup.

Comment: You can do what you describe above, but you will need a package manager running.  The [React Native Running on Device](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/running-on-device.html) explains how  to connect to your development service wirelessly without Expo.

Comment: Thanks for the reploy. I got things working by following the steps in the article you linked to. I thought I had already tried this before, but apparantly I hadn't.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using wifi network point your pc's ip with port(default 8081) for developer menu => Dev Settings => Debug server host & port for device.
And if your backend runs on same pc. you will have to do same without using localhost.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Will check it out.

Answer (score 0):

You can test your app/share your app with friends without package manager by generating the signed apk(**app-release.apk**).